# How to find specific files in folders and do an operation in case they exist

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, sh

I am having some difficulty doing a basic script in sh shell.
What I want to do is simple though:

I want to do a sh script (can also be csh) that looks through a number of folders and for each folder that contains the files I am interested in, it should do a specific operation of pasting the corresponding filename into a sh script with rdseed commands.

The script I wrote in sh shell and doesn't work is:

```
for dir in EV*
do
    echo $dir
    cd $dir 
    if [ -f GEFLE* = true ];
    then
        set dataless = gur_ini_dataless.seed
        for file GEFLE*
        do
            echo "rdseed -d -o 2 -f "$file " -g " $dataless >> runmseed2ahGEFLE.sh
        done
    else
       echo "File does not exists"
    fi
    sleep 0.5
    cd ..
done
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this... I'm adding some comments to the lines...

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in EV*
do
    echo $dir
    cd $dir
    if [ -f GEFLE* ]   # true if at least one FILE named "GEFLE*" exists
    then
        dataless=gur_ini_dataless.seed   # no `set`, no spaces
        for file in GEFLE* # will match all FILES/DIRS/... that start with "GEFLE"
        do
            echo "rdseed -d -o 2 -f $file -g $dataless" >> runmseed2ahGEFLE.sh  # vars are substituted in double quoted strings
        done
    else
       echo "File does not exists"
    fi
    cd ..
done
```

Please note this will only look one level deep into the directories. If you need some resursion you should better use something like

```
for dir in `find . -type d -name 'EV*'`; do
    # ...
done
```

The way I had put this is:

```
for f in `find EV* -name GEFLE* -type f`; do
    echo "rdseed -d -o 2 -f ./$f -g gur_ini_dataless.seed >> ./`dirname $f`/runmseed2ahGEFLE.sh"
done
```